# How to export to HTML in Keynote 09

Tags: keynote, iwork, html

I've created presentation in Keynote 09. Now I want to export it to HTML, but without navigation buttons. After selection Share > Export -> HTML I see only option to select movie quality:

[image]

On [Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4957168?start=0&tstart=0) I've found some instruction on how to configure my export:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't see these all options. Do you have any advices how can I get access to these settings in Keynote HTML export?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the window you see after selecting "Share->Export->HTML" (see [How do I upload a picture here](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/how-do-i-upload-a-picture-on-here) for details)?

Comment: I've just uploaded screenshot to the url http://imgur.com/C60Cr9I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keynote (with iWork 09) does not have Flash options/features in the export to HTML they were available only up to iWork 08. Hopefully someone will be able to tell you how to edit the HTML Keynote now creates so that the navigation controls are not shown.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm able to manually edit generated HTML code, so it's not a problem.